# Error with db persistence on Firestore [Vue3]

Tags: typescript, firebase, google-cloud-firestore, vuejs3

I've been trying to use `enableIndexedDbPersistence` to enable offline capabilities on my Vue3 website using the instructions in the docs [here](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/manage-data/enable-offline#configure_offline_persistence). Everything compiles just fine but the app keeps throwing a vague error in the browser's console log:

```
[2022-03-19T13:02:21.945Z]  @firebase/firestore: Firestore (9.6.4): INTERNAL UNHANDLED ERROR:  Error: Failed to execute 'put' on 'IDBObjectStore': #<Object> could not be cloned.
    at ti.put (webpack-internal:///./node_modules/@firebase/firestore/dist/index.esm2017.js:5969:24)
    at Proxy.ae (webpack-internal:///./node_modules/@firebase/firestore/dist/index.esm2017.js:7166:22)
    at Proxy.updateTargetData (webpack-internal:///./node_modules/@firebase/firestore/dist/index.esm2017.js:7133:21)
    at eval (webpack-internal:///./node_modules/@firebase/firestore/dist/index.esm2017.js:9146:30)
    at Map.forEach (<anonymous>)
    at eval (webpack-internal:///./node_modules/@firebase/firestore/dist/index.esm2017.js:9105:25)
    at eval (webpack-internal:///./node_modules/@firebase/firestore/dist/index.esm2017.js:8508:20)
    at eval (webpack-internal:///./node_modules/@firebase/firestore/dist/index.esm2017.js:5659:49)
    at zs.wrapUserFunction (webpack-internal:///./node_modules/@firebase/firestore/dist/index.esm2017.js:5652:23)
    at zs.wrapSuccess (webpack-internal:///./node_modules/@firebase/firestore/dist/index.esm2017.js:5659:25)

index.esm2017.js?0829:5883 Uncaught (in promise) DOMException: Failed to execute 'put' on 'IDBObjectStore': #<Object> could not be cloned.
    at ti.put (webpack-internal:///./node_modules/@firebase/firestore/dist/index.esm2017.js:5969:24)
    at Proxy.ae (webpack-internal:///./node_modules/@firebase/firestore/dist/index.esm2017.js:7166:22)
    at Proxy.updateTargetData (webpack-internal:///./node_modules/@firebase/firestore/dist/index.esm2017.js:7133:21)
    at eval (webpack-internal:///./node_modules/@firebase/firestore/dist/index.esm2017.js:9146:30)
    at Map.forEach (<anonymous>)
    at eval (webpack-internal:///./node_modules/@firebase/firestore/dist/index.esm2017.js:9105:25)
    at eval (webpack-internal:///./node_modules/@firebase/firestore/dist/index.esm2017.js:8508:20)
    at eval (webpack-internal:///./node_modules/@firebase/firestore/dist/index.esm2017.js:5659:49)
    at zs.wrapUserFunction (webpack-internal:///./node_modules/@firebase/firestore/dist/index.esm2017.js:5652:23)
    at zs.wrapSuccess (webpack-internal:///./node_modules/@firebase/firestore/dist/index.esm2017.js:5659:25)
```

This is the code in my Vue3 TypeScript app:

```
@MutationAction({ mutate: ["db"] })
  async initFirestore(): Promise<any> {
    if (!this.app) return null;
    let db = this.db;
    if (!db) {
      db = initializeFirestore(this.app, {
        cacheSizeBytes: CACHE_SIZE_UNLIMITED,
      });
      await enableIndexedDbPersistence(db);
    }
    return { db };
  }
```

From what I can tell, db persistence is in fact set, but the snapshots I'm listening to are throwing these errors and no longer load any data. I've tried with no luck:

- updating firebase (cur. v9.6.4)
- updating node (cur. v16.14.0)
- clearing all application data and retrying

I'm sort of lost as to what could be causing this issue. Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Might be related to the use
`db = this.db`
might be worth a try to

```
  async initFirestore(): Promise<any> {
    if (!this.app) return null;
    //let db = this.db;
    if (!this.db) {
      this.db = initializeFirestore(this.app, {
        cacheSizeBytes: CACHE_SIZE_UNLIMITED,
      });
      await enableIndexedDbPersistence(this.db);
    }
    return { this.db };
  }
```

Comment: can you please explain? I'm not sure if i follow

Comment: I've changed all the references from `db` to the original function to adqcuire the value, see the difference in the code there is no more `if (db)` and instead is `if (this.db)` and the same for the rest.
I don't think it'll work but that's what I would do next.